# How to amplfy µA from a fast photodiode with a bandwith of 10GHz

Tags: amplifier, photodiode, gain-bandwidth-product

I want to measure faint laserpulses with a step slope (Bandwidth 5-10GHz). I have a photodiode which produces a photocurrent of some µA. Now I need a transimpedance amplifier to convert it to at least 150mV (better 200mV) on 50 Ohm termination so that my time to digital converter can trigger on it. Does such a high gain/high bandwith amplifier even exist? Is there a clever way to use stacked open loop OP-AMPs or a complete different design? What is the highest gain-bandwidth-product achiveable`?

Comment: Is your photodiode bare die or packaged somehow? Do you have capability to process (die attach & wire-bond) bare die?

Comment: challenging to say the least. Fun fact ... 1 uA is 6 electrons per picosecond.

Comment: This is pretty close to "if you have to ask" territory. You have low current and want an extremely high bandwidth transimpedance amplifier. The only thing missing is a noise specification and it probably can be proven impossible.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you need to make your own solution here and not buy something off the shelf from, for example, MKS (former New Focus)?

Comment: Using a 741 probably won't work

Comment: High BW implies low impedance shunt on a high impedance current source. Since you did not specify Z, I suspect your SNR is below threshold by a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot so far for the comments. Let's assume I have a rectangular optical pulse with a peak power of 10µW(@1550nm) and a duration of 1ns. What would be a solution to turn this into a proper voltage signal of around 150mV when I loosen the bandwidth requirement ?

Comment: You are already beyond yer wildest dreams or your budget

Comment: Let's assume that the budget is not the limit. I assume that the diode + amp is in the order of several k$?!?

Comment: The diode and amp is a few hundred dollars (even for the 10 GHz requirement). The expensive part is the equipment needed for optical alignment, wire bonding, testing, etc.

Comment: Can you share the datsheet for your photodiode?

Answer (score 3):

> Let's assume I have a rectangular optical pulse with a peak power of 10µW(@1550nm) and a duration of 1ns. What would be a solution to turn this into a proper voltage signal of around 150mV when I loosen the bandwidth requirement ?

10µW(@1550nm) for 1ns is about 78000 photons.  Assuming 75% QE, you'd get about 60,000 electrons from a photodiode.  You want to turn those 60,000 electrons into 150mV over 1 ns. V=I*R, so 150mV = (60000*1.6E-19/1E-9)*R.  Solve for R and you need a transimpedance gain of 15625 ohms.  Since you are assuming your "faint laser pulses" are actually fairly intense, you don't need a huge amount of gain.

However, finding a photodiode that can meet those bandwidth requirements is going to be tough, so I think you will in fact end up relaxing your bandwidth spec a lot.  As far as commerical products go, you can buy ~1-2 GHz detectors with that transimpedance gain easily enough.